# Magento 2: Add a product programmatically in the checkout page

Tags: checkout, uicomponent, quote

What the client wants is to add a step (product-selector-step.js) before the shipping-step and in that step he shows three options to select representing three simple products.

What I need is to know the best way to add the simple product by Id without having to refresh the page and updating the quote js component regarding the cart totals.

Comment: The checkout page is not a catalog page, it has to be as clear as quick as possible. Why should a customer choose a product in the checkout? Move it to cart or to another place.

Comment: I know that the checkout has to be clear and quick but the client wanted this requirement.  My solution was to use the cart api in the new step and refresh the totals in the ajax success event.